# Jquery size text

Tags: jquery, zooming

I've created a script which is supposed to increase or decrease the size of the text (shown below) but the problem is that the text is remaining the same size when I click on one of the images and pass the parameter `menos`

```
<script>

function increase_text(size,mode) {

    var size_ini=16;
    var size_max=20;
    var size_min=16;


    if (mode=="mas")
    {
        var size_increase = size_ini++;

        alert("ok"+size_increase);

        if (size_increase<20)
        {
            $(".content").css("font-size",""+size_increase+"px");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".content").css("font-size",""+size_max+"px");
        }
    }


    if (mode=="menos")
    {
        var size_increase = size_ini--;

        if (size_increase>=20 || size_increase>=size_min)
        {
            $(".content").css("font-size",""+size_increase+"px");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".content").css("font-size",""+size_min+"px");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Markup**

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;border:0px solid;height:40px;">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/tfw_end/wp-content/themes/thefactoyweb/images/text_decrease.png" onclick="increase_text('1','menos');" style="display:block;float:right;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;" alt="Aumentar Texto" title="Aumentar Texto">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/tfw_end/wp-content/themes/thefactoyweb/images/text_increase.png" onclick="increase_text('1','mas');" style="display:block;float:right;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;" alt="Reducir Texto" title="Reducir Texto"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wn6YJ/

Regards

Comment: estara bien si yo cambie tu pregunta? ... porque el ingles es un poco dificil que entender

Comment: Ok no problem , sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems where 
1. `size_ini` is a local variable, means it is reset on every call of `increase_text`
2. There is a problem in your incremental/decremental logic also, even though `size_ini` is more than `size_max` it is kept incremented, so on the next `decrease` click text will be shown in a much bigger font than allowed.

Use

```
var size_ini = 16;
var size_max = 20;
var size_min = 16;

function increase_text(size, mode) {
    if (mode == "mas") {
        size_ini = size_ini >= size_max ? size_max : size_ini + 1;
    } else if (mode == "menos") {
        size_ini = size_ini <= size_min ? size_min : size_ini - 1;
    }
    $(".content").css("font-size", size_ini + "px");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HS4EL/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not using the `size` variable in your script anywhere, instead you're using other variables (but never that one).

Comment: I try do this but no increase only increase 1 and stopfunction increase_text(size,mode) {

var size_ini=16;
var size_max=20;
var size_min=16;


if (mode=="mas")
{

var size_increase = size_ini + size++;

Comment: @user2202136 Claro, pero hombre ... no estas usando `size` ... tienes que usarlo si quieres por la funcion funcionar

Answer (score 0):

There're a few things in your code will not works.

1. in jsfiddler, you will need to avoid using `onclick="function() {}"` due to scope issue. Use `$("img#reduce").click(function() {});` instead.
2. Your code will not as your initial value for `size_ini` will forever be `16` when you click on the image, since you initiate the `size_ini` in the function scope. Best if you can correct your code and post it if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite, see http://jsfiddle.net/Wn6YJ/1/

It have several problem, the `init` value should not be put in `function`, if you put it in `function`, it will `init` every time